# Server clarifications for "Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint 2013"

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013 and apps.

I just want to make sure I am doing this on the correct server(s). We have 4 serves onsite (2 front-end, ca/application, and a database server) for each of our environments (production/qa).

I just want to double check that I am running the scripts on the correct server(s).

1. "Configure the subscription Settings service application" - Is this done on the central admin/application server or the front-end servers?
2. "You must configure a new name in Domain Name Services (DNS) to host the apps." - Should the DNS be configured for the central admin/application server?
3. What domain should I base the app domain off of? For example, if the corporate domain is mycorp.com, my sites are xyz.com and abc.com. Should I register mycorpapps.com for the app domain?
4. I have two separate environments, a qa environment and a production environment. Do I need to purchase 2 app domains, for example mycorpapps.com and mycorpappsqa.com.
5. Do I need SSL? My sites abs.com and xyz.com are using ssl. Currently the apps will not be referencing external data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. subscription service xan run on any server or multiple servers just like other SharwPoint services.  thîs sevice is unique however in that you have to use powershell to deploy it
2. This is two questions here.  if you want to access CA off the server and not modify Hosts files thn yes you should have a DNS entry.  you will need a DNS entry for your app domain as well.  The MS documentation is verbose but covers the topic well. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236(v=office.15).aspx
3. your app domain can be anything.  it is recommended to use a different domain instead of a sub domain to take advantage of cross domain isolation security present in browsers and SharePoint API.  Sub-Domains can circumvent some of these controls.
4. You xan use the same app domain across farms.  its just a DNS namespace.
5. you don't need SSL.  however your enviroment needs to match.  if content is served via HTTPS then your apps need to as well.  From a practical standpoint all your SharePoint communications should be protected as it makes extensive use of OAuth which includes tokens that can be read in plain text.